# Can I get kicked out of the UK if they leave the EU?

Tags: european-union, england-and-wales, citizenship

I am an Irish citizen and I moved to the UK a few years ago. Now they are going to vote whether to leave the EU. I know they might decide not to apply the law retrospectively but by law- would they be able to deport me?

Can they take my benefits?

Comment: You're asking about the effect of laws that do not yet exist.  At the end of the day, a sovereign nation can make any laws it wants.  In principle, the UK could certainly make a law (amending its constitution if necessary) that all Irish citizens had to forfeit all their assets and march out of the country while wearing silly hats and dancing to Gangnam Style.  Is it likely?  No, but that's a question of politics, not law.  So http://politics.stackexchange.com might be a better place for your question.

Comment: @NateEldridge I believe this has already been discussed on http://expatriates.stackexchange.com. The answer is that Irish citizens have a right under UK law to settle in the UK, which predates the EU, so it's likely not a problem. Also I suppose that citizens of other EU countries already established in the UK will probably be fine, but of course that's pure speculation.